# Logs aren't arriving in Cloud Logging from Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I have a VM instance running in GCE (using the Container Optimised OS) and within that I have an actively running container that is generating json logs. I can see these logs when I navigate to `/var/lib/docker/containers/<CONTAINER_IMAGE>/<CONTAINER_IMAGE>-json.log`.

In the same Instance, another docker container is running using the image `gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:1.8.4`. This was automatically set up when I created the VM.

The VM has permission to access to Cloud Logging and the Cloud Logging API is enabled. I have also followed the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/logging)  and added `google-logging-enabled` to the metadata with a value of `true`.

When the VM is started, the logging agent seems to spin up correctly and emits a log saying that it is tailing the log file of the docker container I want logs for, however the logs within that file never appear in Google Logging. Below is a screenshot of the logs that do make it to Cloud Logging:

[image]

[image]

I have had this issue for a while now so would be very grateful for any help with this issue! Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the json logs I was providing, the time format used was not being accepted by fluentd. I've been able to get around that by adding:

```
reserve_time true
```

to the filter in the default config. Now the config ignores any nested fields with time specified. I learned of this from [here](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/2073#issuecomment-622551035).

Answer (score 0):

Google logging uses a fluentd to catch the logs.

You can [reconfugure fluentd to include additional log files](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration#third-party_application_log_input_configuration).

Create a file `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/my_app_name.conf` and put in the file a  line in a format `path /path/to/my/log`. Here are more examples in the [fluentd documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#path).

You can also specify how the file is going to be [parsed](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser): as a [single](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/none) `string` type field or in more structured way (more convinient when you're looking for something). Again - here's some more info about [fluentd's output plugins](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration#cloud-fluentd-config).

Finally go ahead and read the [`fluentd` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/configuration) to have a better understanding on using this tool.

Comment: No it didn't, hence why I hadn't accepted it as the answer. I have added the resolution myself and will close the ticket in 4 hours when stackoverflow lets me.
Thank you @Wojtek_B for taking the time to answer though.